Steam Build Depot Time not localized
When uploading my build to steam the time shown for the build upload is some completly different timezone. (Probably USA west coast). I can't find out how to show it for my timezone
it shows 3am which for me was 1pm
Time
Tried to research here but there doesn't seem to be any info.
https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/application/builds
